# Что означает точка в примере ниже (я про "script.src = src;")

Tags: javascript, ооп, операторы

```
    function loadScript(src, callback) {
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;

  script.onload = () => callback(script);

  document.head.append(script);
}
```

Я не могу понять, где взялось свойство *src* у переменной *script*, и вообще что это такое, в моем понимании переменная *script* должна быть объявлена как объект, там должны быть записаны ключи, один из которых -  src

Comment: Есть **[DOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)** и `script` - это элемент этого ДОМа со всеми вытекающими

Answer (score 1):

Давайте разбирать

```
function loadScript(src, callback) {// объявление функции с аргументами src и callback
  let script = document.createElement('script'); // создание элемента html элемента script
  script.src = src; // присваивание свойству src тега script значение из переменной src 

  script.onload = () => callback(script); // назначение обработчика события onload элемента script

  document.head.append(script);// добавление в head документа созданного script
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В строке `let script = document.createElement('script');` создаётся [элемент](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element) [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/DOM) [script](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement). По приведённым ссылкам (в дебагере/консоли) Вы можете видеть, что у созданного объекта имеется много предопределённых свойств и событий. Некоторые из них принадлежат непосредственно script, некоторые наследуются от родительских классов/интерфейсов. Далее в строке `script.src = src;` через точку осуществляется доступ к свойству src и его значение устанавливается значением параметра функции src.
В строке `script.onload = () => callback(script);` в обработчик события load добавляется callback-функция, которая будет вызвана, когда событие произойдёт.
В последней строке `document.head.append(script);` созданный элемент/объект script с добавленным к нему обработчиком события load добавляется к первому элементу [head](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/head) на странице.